# inconsistent results, simple Rock Paper Scissors game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I'm very new to Python and currently just trying to play around with some core concepts like data structures to get a better understanding of how to call on certain keys and values.

I'm running into very inconsistent results with the below code, when I (the player) plays 'scissors' and NPC plays 'rock' I (the player) still somehow win, other combinations of rock, paper, scissors gives the correct result (from what I can tell) eg. paper vs rock, scissors vs paper and I'm unsure why.

I've attached an image of my code, as copy and pasting it seems to produce ugly paragraphs.
[code in pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKri9.png)

For actual code:

```
import random
d = {'rock': {'rock': 'tie', 'scissors': 'win', 'paper': 'lose'},
     'paper': {'paper': 'tie', 'rock': 'win', 'scissors': 'lose'},
     'scissors': {'scissors': 'tie', 'paper': 'win', 'rock': 'lose'}}

d_l = list(d)

def umbrella():
    player_1_name = input('insert name')
    player_2_name = 'npc'
    player_1_and_npc_actions_and_check_winner(player_1_name, player_2_name)

def player_1_and_npc_actions_and_check_winner(x, y):
    winner = 0
    while winner == 0:
        p1 = input('please choose a rock = 1, paper = 2, scissors = 3  ')
        p1_n = int(p1)
        p_c = d_l[p1_n - 1]
        print(p_c)
        npc_choice = random.choice(d_l)
        print(npc_choice)
        if p_c == npc_choice:
            print('TIE')
            winner += 0
            return
        elif p_c in d.get(npc_choice, 'lose'):
            print(f'{x} wins!')
        elif npc_choice in d.get(p_c, 'lose'):
            print(f'{y} wins!')
    return

umbrella()
```

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating the code. Is it not possible to just reference both keys and extract the predefined result? Since both are dictionaries for your problem can't you just get d['scissors']['rock']? and apply the same logic for everything? Or do you want specifically a solution for the code as is?

Comment: Note that if you simply had the NPC enter an integer number, then the result of `(players_choice - npc_choice) % 3` tells you that: the player wins if the result is 1, the NPC wins if the result is 2, and if the result is zero its a tie. Also note that `winner = 0` is fulfilling the role that booleans are designed for. You should instead have something like `winner_found = False` and then use that as the condition for your `while`.

Comment: To build off what The Grand J is saying, you only need to check for a winning move or a tying move: if a player neither wins nor ties, the only other possible outcome is a loss. Since you know that ties only happen when both players choose the same move, you only need to keep a dictionary of winning moves.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. Greatly appreciated.